# form in file PHP not post UTF-8

Tags: php, html, sql

I use PHP to create FAQ form, but it doesn't display UTF-8 although SQL data utf-8_general_ci
[image: index image error font utf-8]
[image: sql error font utf-8]

I have 2 file: faq.php and index.php

Answer (score 3):

IMHO there are several places could cause the problem:

- Encoding of the page with the form

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content=" text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  ```
- The form encoding of the form itself

  ```
  <form accept-charset="utf-8">
  ```
- The encoding of the SQL connection

  ```
  charset utf8;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Add HTML tag `<meta charset="utf-8" />` to `head` tag of every page.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure your page is utf8 as well, i.e. it must it include the `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag.

You should also check your database and make sure the data is stored correctly. If it comes from a non-utf8 source, it might get corrupted if you simply copy and paste. What I usually do is to use some text editor to change the text encoding to utf8 before uploading to the database.

Answer (score 2):

When opening `PDO` connection, make sure the client connection use UTF-8:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname",
              'username', 'password',
              array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

This can also be set directly to `my.cnf` so you won't have to set it separately for each  connection:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```